# school project in context of in-memory database school

Tags: database, in-memory-database, in-memory

In my class project I have to use in-memory database. I know database in generally and how to deal with, but the main problem is that i have to use it in context of application (mobile, desktop or web). I have no idea where can I use it. I find context like testing and many other, but it is too complex for me. I have to show general use of in-memory database and differences between another type of databases. Thanks for all advices and your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today only came across this question. The main difference between in-memory database and regular database is: performance. It takes lot of IO to bring the data from disk (hard-disk) to memory (RAM) when a query is executed. The IO cost usually affects the query performance. The in-memory databases avoid the disk read, during a query, by pre-loading the data into inmemory area(resides in RAM). This helps in reducing the delay in real-time analytical queries (OLAP).

Also, one another difference in in-memory database is it mainly focuses on read-only data. To put it in another way, data which is less susceptible to change is ideal candidate for inmemory database. [Example](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/in-memory-database) data sets will be stock market data, webtraffic data etc.,.

While most of the in-memory databases focus on read-only data, Oracle's new [Database Inmemory](http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/features/database-in-memory-option/index.html) (DBIM) supports both OLAP & OLTP queries on inmemory.